# How to write unit tests for MS Bot Builder Node SDK bots?

Tags: node.js, botframework

I'm trying to find if the MS Bot framework provides any resource / guidelines for writing unit tests for bots based on Node SDK (Specifically, I using the direct line channel).

If not, how can tools like Mocha be used to write test cases to test various dialogs.

I'm using `restify`, as below:

```
/**-----------------------------------------------------------------
 * Setup Chat-Bot
 -----------------------------------------------------------------*/
// Create chat connector for communicating with the Bot Framework Service
var connector = new builder.ChatConnector({
    appId: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_ID || config.appId,
    appPassword: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_PASSWORD || config.appPassword
});


// Initialize bot
var bot = universalBot(connector);


/**-----------------------------------------------------------------
 * Setup Server
 -----------------------------------------------------------------*/
var server = restify.createServer();

server.listen(process.env.port || 8080, function () {
    console.log('%s listening to %s', server.name, server.url);
});

server.pre(restify.pre.sanitizePath());
server.use(restify.queryParser());


/**---------------------------------------------------------------
 * Routes
 ----------------------------------------------------------------*/
server.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send("Hello from Chatbot API");
});

server.post('/api/messages', connector.listen());
```

Thanks for you input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the best source at this point would be to check the unit tests in `Node.js` done by the Bot Framework team on the [BotBuilder repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder).

See [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/tree/master/Node/core/tests). They are using `Mocha` too.

[image]

Comment: No, that I'm aware of. The current version of the docs doesn't have anything  around testing.

Answer (score 2):

Check out https://github.com/microsoftly/BotTester. It makes testing with Mocha and Chai much easier than the tests in the botbuilder src. E.g.

```
it('Can simulate conversation', () => {
    bot.dialog('/', [(session) => {
        new builder.Prompts.text(session, 'Hi there! Tell me something you like')
    }, (session, results) => {
        session.send(`${results.response} is pretty cool.`);
        new builder.Prompts.text(session, 'Why do you like it?');
    }, (session) => session.send('Interesting. Well, that\'s all I have for now')]);


    const {
        executeDialogTest,
        SendMessageToBotDialogStep,
    } = testSuiteBuilder(bot);

    return executeDialogTest([
        new SendMessageToBotDialogStep('Hola!', 'Hi there! Tell me something you like'),
        new SendMessageToBotDialogStep('The sky', ['The sky is pretty cool.', 'Why do you like it?']),
        new SendMessageToBotDialogStep('It\'s blue', 'Interesting. Well, that\'s all I have for now')
    ])
})
```

It also allows for inspection of session state at any point within the dialog. E.g

```
it('Can inspect session state', () => {
    bot.dialog('/', [(session) => {
        new builder.Prompts.text(session, 'What would you like to set data to?')
    }, (session, results) => {
        session.userData = { data: results.response };
        session.save();
    }]);


    const {
        executeDialogTest,
        SendMessageToBotDialogStep,
        InspectSessionDialogStep,
    } = testSuiteBuilder(bot);

    return executeDialogTest([
        // having expected responses is not necessary
        new SendMessageToBotDialogStep('Start this thing!'),
        new SendMessageToBotDialogStep('This is data!'),
        new InspectSessionDialogStep((session) => {
            expect(session.userData).not.to.be.null;
            expect(session.userData.data).to.equal('This is data!');
        })
    ])
})
```

Theres a bunch of additional functionality for testing that it works with, I'd suggest referring to the docs for a little more insight.